# Placing of list within interactive

Tags: interactive

I am making an interactive function and encountering a difficulty on the placing of the command `list` to set the function argument.

This code

```
  (interactive
   (list
    (let ( (rqmatch t)  (initpk "mixed")  (dflt "extended")
           (cseq '("expression" "mixed" "hlsexp"
                      "bracemk" "extended" "disable")) )

      (+ 2 2)
      (completing-read "Flare_type: " cseq nil rqmatch initpk
         'flare-hist dflt))))
```

versus the following

```
  (interactive
    (let ( (rqmatch t)  (initpk "mixed")  (dflt "extended")
       (cseq '("expression" "mixed" "hlsexp"
                     "bracemk" "extended" "disable")) )
      (+ 2 2)
      (list 
         (completing-read "Flare_type: " cseq nil rqmatch initpk
            'flare-hist dflt))))
```

Comment: That is up to you, although I guess for most people, your second version makes more sense. Personally, I don't see any reason here to use the `let` at all (but you might have a good argument for it). Also, I am not sure if the formatting that you use here is also the formatting that you use 'in production'. In that case, I would recommend having a look at some 'random' Emacs lisp source files to see the 'common way for formatting'.

Comment: Using `let` was just a test for cases where they would be required.  Emacs source files show a variety of implementations.  So there is really no common way.  Although we can agree on what makes it easier for working with other people's code.

Comment: A little question regarding the first implementation.  Have read the introduction to emacs lisp,  As I understand, the body of the `let` clause is the part that returns values from expressions, which are then collected in a list to set the argument values.

Comment: The comment about looking at source files was related to your formatting. To me, the formatting of Emacs source files generally looks quite consistent.

Comment: Only the value of the last expression in the `let` clause its body is returned... this is a 'good argument' for using the second version

Comment: Emacs source files using `list` are quite basic, just list of expressions with perhaps `if` statements.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-to-format-your-code, it is more or less those extra spaces in the `let` that make your code look strange to me. And additionally, I think I mostly see those local variables definitions getting placed on separate lines like in [this example](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Sample-let-Expression.html) (although that is probably a matter of preference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the special form function `let` should be the last evaluation inside it.  The list will only contain `completing-read` value.  `list` should be the last call inside `let` if one wants it to return a list.