# Using `let` with `list`

Tags: list

I have read that by default, a function returns the value of the last expression evaluated as the return value.

Does it mean that when using special form `let`, the value of the last expression in the `let` body is what is returned?

If I use `list` in the following way, only `(region-end)` will be inserted in the list?

```lisp
(list
  (let ( (dflt t) ) 
    (region-beginning)
    (region-end)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Function"* `let` is a **special form**.

Like Lisp macros, special forms do *not* follow any particular rule about evaluating arguments or what to return. Each special form has its own such behavior.

Consult the doc of a given special form for the answer (or the implementation, if the doc doesn't tell you). It suffices to use `C-h f let`:

> **`let`** is a **special form** in `C source code`.
>
> `(let VARLIST BODY...)`
>
> Bind variables according to `VARLIST` then eval `BODY`.
>
> **The value of the last form in `BODY` is returned.**
>
> Each element of `VARLIST` is a symbol (which is bound to `nil`)
> or a list `(SYMBOL VALUEFORM)` (which binds `SYMBOL` to the value of `VALUEFORM`).
>
> All the `VALUEFORM`s are evalled before any symbols are bound.

Emacs often refers in a general way to functions, macros, and special forms as *"functions"*.  The predicate that tests this sense of the word "function" is `fboundp`:

- `(fboundp 'let)` returns **`t`**
- `(fboundp 'forward-char)` returns `t`

What Lisp more specifically calls a *"function"* is something that can be `funcall`ed or `apply`ed.  The predicate that tests this sense of the word "function" is `functionp`:

- `(functionp 'let)` returns **`nil`**
- `(functionp 'forward-char)` returns `t`

Answer (score 2):

EDIT add simplified test version

Here is a simplified test, that only contains the essence.

Evaluate

```lisp
(list (let () 'a 'b))
```

Then for even better understanding, also evaluate

```lisp
(let () (list 'a 'b))
```

Now draw your conclusions

END EDIT The redundant original answer is kept here below

Why not just test it?
Evaluate

```lisp
(defun test ()
  (interactive)
  (print
   (list (let ((dummy t))
           (region-beginning)
           (region-end)))))
```

then select a region and run `M-x test`. How many values does the list contain?

Then place the print list inside the let and do the same

```lisp
(defun test ()
  (interactive)
    (let ((dummy t))
      (print
       (list (region-beginning)
             (region-end)))))
```

Now what (how many values in the list) do you get?

Comment: Can I test it in the scratch buffer, because currently I have a problem with my init files.

Comment: Yes, that is more or less what the scratch buffer is for...

Comment: So you could answer your own question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/72589/placing-of-list-within-interactive?noredirect=1#comment117538_72589) now. Because, as you have found here now, it does matter where you place the let when you add multiple elements to the list. The implied answer here would be a perfect answer there (you would get my upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

> `let` Bind variables according to VARLIST then eval BODY.

Then the value of `let` should be the last evaluation inside it. Your list will only contain `(region-end)` value. `list` should be the last call inside `let` if you want it to return a list.

You can look at `let` as an inline scope.